# Inserting HTML fragments returned from a JSON response into the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, json, jquery

Hopefully this isn't a stupid question so here goes:

I am using a Web Service that's returning json like this through a jquery post request:

```
{
"response": [
    [
        {
            "class": "class blah blah blah",
            "index": 0,
            "item": {
                "imageurl": "image.jpg",
                "description": "<span class=\"span1\"><span class=\"string1\">10 Great Gift Ideas for<\/span><span class=\"string2\">Valentines<\/span><span class=\"string3\">Day<\/br><\/span><span class=\"string4\">Only<br />5 days left<\/span><\/span>" 
            },
            "prices": null 
        } 
    ] 
]
}
```

That is just one part of the response.  I need to extract the response.item.description and insert that into a div on the page but when I do, the extra \ are still there which causes the display to break.  Is there a proper way to handle the html fragments?  I was thinking that I could use a regex to check to see is a \ was followed by a " / etc and strip it.  I was also thinking if I changed the data on the server side to be HTML encoded than maybe it wouldn't get escaped but I would rather keep the data the way it is.

Is there anything built into jQuery or javascript that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

i think you're looking for unescape().  you should be able to call it like

```
unescape(response[0].item.description)
```

Comment: I had tried that before, but that just prints the HTML into the page without the slashes when I do $("#someDIv").html(unescape(response[0].item.description));  I need it to actually render as HTML.

Comment: not really sure what you mean, it is real html...  and renders properly.  take a look at this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/r26d6/1/) for an example of it working.

Comment: This must have something to do with how I am processing the data.  I am using jquery templating.  When I take my data and use your example it works, but when I try and have the templating api call unescape its not working correctly.  I will try to track it down.  thanks.

Comment: Watch out: The unescape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use decodeURI() or decodeURIComponent() instead.